# Fire Dataflow trigger only once a pane is complete

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

Is there a way to setup a trigger that only fires once when a pane is complete? By "complete" I mean specifically when the watermark is past the end of the window plus any allowed lateness. I do not want any intermediate triggers to fire before then.
The way I'm currently attempting to "fake" this behavior is by setting `.withAllowedLateness(Duration.standardHours(1), ClosingBehavior.FIRE_ALWAYS))`, then filtering the results by checking `if(c.pane().isLast()){ ...`
or more precisely, something along the lines of:

```
Pipeline p = Pipeline.create(PipelineOptionsFactory.fromArgs(args).withValidation().create());
p.apply(PubsubIO.Read.named("ReadFromPubsub").timestampLabel("myts").subscription(INPUT_TOPIC))
.apply("Window", Window.<String>into(Sessions.withGapDuration(Duration.standardMinutes(5)))
    .accumulatingFiredPanes()
    .withAllowedLateness(Duration.standardHours(1), ClosingBehavior.FIRE_ALWAYS))
.apply("Combine", Combine.<String, Metric>perKey(Foo.Merge))
.apply(ParDo.named("FilterComplete").of(Foo.FilterComplete));
```

where `FilterComplete()` looks something like:

```
static final DoFn<String, String> FilterComplete = new DoFn<String, String>() {
  @Override
  public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
    if(c.pane().isLast()){
      c.output(c.element());
    }
  }
};
```

While this approach seems to work, it seems like a waste of resources to filter out all the un-used triggers. But more importantly, if I let the streaming job run for multiple days, it starts to throw `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Garbage collection hold . . .` exceptions, so I'm looking for ways to re-factor.

The full exception is as follows:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Garbage collection hold 2017-07-16T14:55:43.999Z cannot be before input watermark 2017-07-16T15:34:15.000Z
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.worker.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:199)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWatermarkHold.addGarbageCollectionHold(DataflowWatermarkHold.java:402)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWatermarkHold.addEndOfWindowOrGarbageCollectionHolds(DataflowWatermarkHold.java:279)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWatermarkHold.access$000(DataflowWatermarkHold.java:55)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWatermarkHold$1.read(DataflowWatermarkHold.java:534)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWatermarkHold$1.read(DataflowWatermarkHold.java:486)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowReduceFnRunner.onTrigger(DataflowReduceFnRunner.java:971)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowReduceFnRunner.emit(DataflowReduceFnRunner.java:902)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowReduceFnRunner.onTimers(DataflowReduceFnRunner.java:765)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowGABWViaWindowSetFn.processElement(DataflowGABWViaWindowSetFn.java:89)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:49)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.DoFnRunnerBase.processElement(DoFnRunnerBase.java:139)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.LateDataDroppingDoFnRunner.processElement(LateDataDroppingDoFnRunner.java:67)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.SimpleParDoFn.processElement(SimpleParDoFn.java:188)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.ForwardingParDoFn.processElement(ForwardingParDoFn.java:42)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.DataflowWorkerLoggingParDoFn.processElement(DataflowWorkerLoggingParDoFn.java:47)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.ParDoOperation.process(ParDoOperation.java:55)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.OutputReceiver.process(OutputReceiver.java:52)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.runReadLoop(ReadOperation.java:221)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.ReadOperation.start(ReadOperation.java:182)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.util.common.worker.MapTaskExecutor.execute(MapTaskExecutor.java:69)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.process(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:719)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker.access$600(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:95)
at com.google.cloud.dataflow.sdk.runners.worker.StreamingDataflowWorker$8.run(StreamingDataflowWorker.java:801)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Could you share the entire exception? Could you elaborate on why you want to wait longer after the watermark has past? If you're doing this because the watermark estimation is advancing too fast (thus causing too much late data) you could look at modifying the source so that the watermark estimation is basically an hour slower. Then you don't need any allowed lateness and you can just trigger when the watermark passes the end of the window.

Comment: I updated the question with the entire exception.The reason I want to wait is that I need to support late data (log files don't always arrive on time), and it's much easier to process the data downstream if I only have a single record that's guaranteed to have everything (late data included), instead of getting discrete or accumulating pieces of a single record that would require some sort of upsert logic to handle. It's the necessity of holding a window open until I can be certain that all the log data has arrived.

Comment: @BenChambers Just wanted to follow up on the trigger question. Is there a single trigger that will fire when the watermark passes the end of the window plus allowed lateness? Thanks for your help.

Comment: There isn't currently. In general, you shouldn't be using triggers to reduce the amount of late data. If the watermark estimation is producing too much late data, you should adjust that so that when the watermark passes the end of the window there is less potential for late data.

Comment: How did you handle it at the end?